# Add for loop inside 'echo' in PHP

Tags: php, loops

Is it possible in PHP `echo` to have `for loop` inside of it?
Something like this:

```
echo "This are the list" . for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++) { echo $variable1 . $variable2} . "End";
```

My code goes like this.

but I still experience error.

Comment: ...and what is this error you receive? It might help others.

Comment: what accually you want.What will be the output.You no need to put `.` before and after for loop

Comment: no, you cannot concatenate the control structure with it

Comment: simple answer, i don't think keyword `for` accepts operator `.`

Comment: or is it possible to store the result of the for loop in a variable???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope it's not going to work like that.

You have two options.

## Option 1

```
$temp_string = '';
for ($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++)
{
 $temp_string .= $variable1 . $variable2;
}
echo "This are the list".$temp_string;
```

## Option 2

```
echo "This are the list";
for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++)
{
 echo $variable1 . $variable2;
} 
echo "End";
```

Comment: Hi Techie, Thanks a lot.. Option 1 solved my headache. 
I owe you a cup of coffee. :D

Answer (score 4):

Loops dont go inside an echo statement. Separate them

```
echo "This are the list";
for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++)
{
 echo $variable1 . $variable2;
} 
echo "End";
```

A more readable version of the output would be generated by:

```
echo "This is the list: <br>";
for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++)
{
 echo $variable1. " ". $variable2."<br>";
} 
echo "End";
```

Answer (score 1):

No. [`echo` only accepts strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php); it cannot serve as a code block like a function or method. But you can certainly do this:

```
echo "This are the list";
for ($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++) {
    echo $variable1 . $variable2;
}
echo "End";
```

Answer (score 0):

**No** you cannot do like that you cannot loop in echo statement, you can do like this :

```
$text = 'This are the list ';

for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++){
    $text .=  $variable1.$variable2;
}

$text .= 'End';

echo $text;
```